# php on iis6 config question

Tags: php, iis-6

I have never used php but have been asked to set up a site for some code we have inherited.  I have configured php to run on iis6 sucessfully however there is one issue.

This page will work properly...

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But this will not...

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

How do I get the latter to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable short tags in your `php.ini` file.
Its the section with `--disable-short-tags` in it.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually short_open_tag=off, but you're answer set me on the right path.